# Automatically add Image frame to taken screenshot

Tags: ios, screenshot, frame, layer

I would like to automatically add a image frame to a taken screenshot. Here´s the code I´m using to take the screenshot. Any Ideas to put this image around the taken screenshot?

For the completeness: I want to give the user a option to share this beautiful screenshot with it´s frame on Twitter or Facebook.

BTW: That´s my first app as programmer, so please give me full solution or a tutorial to do this…

Screenshot: http://techstern.de/app/screenshot1.png 
Frame I want to put around it: http://oi45.tinypic.com/2qvv2tv.jpg 
Prototype: visit https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg1nW.png

Code

```
- (UIImage *)screenshot
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

*I can´t put more than 2 links in this article because I´ve just signed up.

Comment: Look how to merge image.

Comment: GPU Image is your friend (GPUImageMaskFilter).  GPUImage is very simple to use so you shouldn't need any tutorial etc.

Comment: I know, it's maybe not the best solution, but it's the easiest: Just render the `UIImage` in the current context, before you render the actual layer?

Comment: Could you maybe give me a detailed explanation to this? This is my first App ever… Yours faithfully

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution I proposed in the comments.

```
- (UIImage *)screenShot {
    UIImage *frame = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame"];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [frame drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:1.0];

    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, xCordinateOfScreenshotInFrame, yCordinateOfScreenshotInFrame);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Seems good, but unfortunately does´t work. Xcode says there are 2 errors: http://techstern.de/app/screenshot_error.png

Comment: Take a look at the code again, you must've copied an older edit.

Comment: Yes there was one code line, but it didn´t change much: http://techstern.de/app/screenshot_error2.png

Comment: Replace the variables with real values, I'll not do anything for you. I provided a solution, but you have to adjust it to fit for your specific problem.