# Add background to screenshot

Tags: ios, uiimage

I would like to add a background to my taken screenshot, but something went wrong. The return of the image is only the background without the screenshot. Here´s my code, can you fix it please?

```
- (UIImage *)screenshot
{
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphoneframe.png"];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImage.size);
[backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height)];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[screenshot drawInRect:CGRectMake(backgroundImage.size.width - screenshot.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height - screenshot.size.height, screenshot.size.width, screenshot.size.height)];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

return image;
}
```

Background/Frame I want to put around the screenshot: http://oi45.tinypic.com/2qvv2tv.jpg 
Prototype Image, which should be returned: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg1nW.png

**Update**: The problem was solved with the tips from @panayot-panayotov and @jrturton - the idea was to remove second `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` & place `UIGraphicsEndImage Context();` above `return Image;`, but now the picture is like this: pbs.twimg.com/media/BnlkN9wIAAEG-ue.jpg:large - **how can we fix this? Any ideas?**

Comment: Put `UIGraphicsEndImageContext();` above `return image;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically add Image frame to taken screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630270/automatically-add-image-frame-to-taken-screenshot)

Comment: Why did you create another question? You could have edit your previous question pointing new issue, since it's just a continuation from your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630270/automatically-add-image-frame-to-taken-screenshot

Comment: Ok I followed your tips (remove second UIGraphicsBeginImageContext & place `UIGraphicsEndImage Context();` above `return Image;`, but now the picture is like this: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BnlkN9wIAAEG-ue.jpg:large - how can I fix it?

Comment: has nobody an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating two image contexts, and drawing a different image in each one. Don't create the second context (`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext...`), and move the end context call until after you've taken out the final image, and you should be fine.

It's also worth noting that you should use the newer 'with options' version when making an image context - this will allow you to draw properly on retina devices.

Comment: any idea how to fix this bug? https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BnlrfA-CEAA3jvE.jpg:large

Comment: You need to translate the drawing context before drawing the screenshot, since it is starting at 0,0. The answer in your other question has this.